# 403 Error - Apache VirtualHost - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

i recently install ubuntu 22.04 and try to use LAMP on it.
but i have problem with VirtualHost.
i want use virtualhosts with a local domain like: test.local
i added this domain to /etc/hosts and add this configuration to my test.local.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.local
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/soroush/Sites/test
        <Directory "/home/soroush/Sites/test" >
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
           Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and then run: a2ensite test.local.conf
but when i open test.local in my browser, apache show me a 403 error.
Sites/test folder and files have 0777 permission and owner is my username.
what i should to do for fix this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my soluttion was a downgrade to 20.04 ;) sorry if I can't give you a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, 
I switch back to fedora ... :)
Unfortunately, Ubuntu is becoming more and more like Windows ...

Comment: Not a valid answer just add your user to apache group

Answer (score 2):

Add your user to the apache group then it's working fine

`sudo usermod -g www-data <YOUR_USERNAME>`

Answer (score 1):

> By default, Ubuntu does not allow access through the web browser to
> any file apart of those located in /var/www, public_html directories
> (when enabled) and /usr/share (for web applications). If your site is
> using a web document root located elsewhere (such as in /srv) you may
> need to whitelist your document root directory in
> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.  The default Ubuntu document root is
> /var/www/html. You can make your own virtual hosts under /var/www.

This is different to previous releases which provides better security
out of the box.

To solve the problem:

1. Move your source code to /var/www

   Example: /var/www/site

2.Fix your Virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.local
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/site
  <Directory "/var/www/site" >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I need my site files under the home directory.
I switch back to fedora ... :)
Ubuntu is becoming more and more like Windows ...

Answer (score 0):

All tihs info are ok, I only add a row of my site into the /etc/hosts file:

127.0.0.1     my-site